# K-candidates on Hunt & McIlroy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, diff, lcs

I'm trying to understand the algorithm of [Hunt & McIlroy](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/diff.pdf) but I don't understand how to find the *k-candidates*.

I know that the *k-candidates* are pairs of indices such that:

- A_i = B_j
- P_(ij) > max(P_(i-1, j), P_(i, j-1))

The second point implies two properties of *k-candidates*:

There is a common subsequence of length *k* in the first *i* lines of file *A* and the first *j* lines of file *B*.
There are no common subsequences of length *k* for any fewer than i lines of file *A* or *j* lines of file *B*.

Now how do I get the picture that's on the paper?
What are the *k-candidates*? And as I unite them once they have found them?

I also searched on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93McIlroy_algorithm) but it is much more clear..
Thanks

Comment: VtC unclear what you're asking because this is not a specific question about the algorithm. Once you understand the quadratic algorithm fully, you can think of H--M as the same dynamic program but operating on a sparse representation of the rows, with entries only for discontinuities.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am reading the paper and I didn't understand how the algorithm works and I have not found sites where it was explained clearly..